# How to I use a loop to change categorical data into binary data?

Tags: r, loops, data-manipulation

I have a data set that compares improvement in student's performance to their studying method. The categorical parameter is the studying method and the three options are NO (no assistance), FULL (yes assistance), and CHECK (assistance as needed). To set up my regression, I need to set x1=1 if a student had FULL assistance else x1=0. I also need to set an x2=1 if a student was labeled as CHECK, else x2=0. I will also need to do the same for NO help (x3=1 if ASSIST='NO' else x3=0). Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
if (ACCHW$ASSIST<-"FULL") { x1=1
} else {
x1=0
}
```

But I get the ERROR: Error in if (ACCHW$ASSIST <- "FULL") { : 
  argument is not interpretable as logical.

I'm new to creating loops in R, advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `<-` is the assignment operator and not a comparator, which are things like `==`, `!=` `<=`, etc. That's your first problem. Did you mean `<=`?

Comment: Loop seems unnecessary here. Try `x1 = ifelse(ACCH$ASSIST == "FULL", 1, 0)`

Comment: I tried this. When I ran my regression p4.53=lm(ACCHW$IMPROVE~x1 +x2, data=ACCHW)
summary(p4.53) I get no beta estimates... i need beta estimates.

Answer (score 0):

It would be enough to create a new data frame comparing `ASSIST` to each of it's values, and `cbind` that to the origiginal data frame. Using the following data:

```r
ACCHW <- data.frame(ASSIST = c("NO", "FULL", "CHECK"), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Try this:

```r
cbind(ACCHW,
      data.frame(x1 = ACCHW$ASSIST == "NO",
                 x2 = ACCHW$ASSIST == "FULL",
                 x3 = ACCHW$ASSIST == "CHECK"
                 )
      )

#### OUTPUT ####

  ASSIST    x1    x2    x3
1     NO  TRUE FALSE FALSE
2   FULL FALSE  TRUE FALSE
3  CHECK FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Remember that `TRUE == 1` and `FALSE == 0`. If you really want 0s and 1s do the same as above, but with `as.integer`:

```r
cbind(ACCHW,
      data.frame(x1 = as.integer(ACCHW$ASSIST == "NO"),
                 x2 = as.integer(ACCHW$ASSIST == "FULL"),
                 x3 = as.integer(ACCHW$ASSIST == "CHECK")
                 )
      )
```

Comment: When I try to run this in a lm function, object x1 is not found. I need to create a model that looks like this: Y(improvement score)= Bo + B1 X1 (Full assist) + B2 X2 (check).

Comment: @valarievil I don't know how you wrote your formula, but `x1` is definitely there. R is case sensitive - are you using the right `x1` vs. `X1`?

Comment: capitalization is not the issue. the code: x1 = ifelse(ACCHW$ASSIST == "FULL", 1, 0)
x2 = ifelse(ACCHW$ASSIST == "CHECK", 1, 0)

#cbind(ACCHW,
#      data.frame(x1 = as.integer(ACCHW$ASSIST == "NO"),
#                 x2 = as.integer(ACCHW$ASSIST == "FULL"),
#                 x3 = as.integer(ACCHW$ASSIST == "CHECK")
#                 )
#      )


p4.53=lm(ACCHW$IMPROVE~x1 +x2, data=ACCHW)
summary(p4.53)

alias(p4.53)                                  #gives me no beta coefficients for x1 and x2

Comment: @valarievil when I test it with my own data everything works fine, so the problem doesn't seem to have to do with my solution. Check your code for syntax errors and make sure your data is appropriate for multiple regression.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a **dplyr** alternative!

```
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(ASSIST = c("NO", "FULL", "CHECK"))

df %>% 
  mutate(x1 = ASSIST == "NO",
         x2 = ASSIST == "FULL",
         x3 = ASSIST == "CHECK") %>% 
  mutate_at(c("x1", "x2", "x3"), as.integer) # Converts to binary
```

Answer (score 0):

Base R Solution:

```
cbind(ASSIST = ACCHW$ASSIST, data.frame(lapply(data.frame(setNames(
  sapply(ACCHW$ASSIST, `==`, ACCHW$ASSIST),
         c(names(ACCHW), ACCHW$ASSIST))), as.integer)))
```

Data thanks (@ gersht):

```
ACCHW <- data.frame(ASSIST = c("NO", "FULL", "CHECK"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```